# When I make PDF then error is 'Trying to access array offset on value of type null' in dompdf in Laravel

Tags: laravel, dompdf

I am new in Laravel. When I try to make a PDF file then some time working properly but some time is giving an exception:

> Trying to access array offset on value of type null

I am using `"barryvdh/laravel-dompdf": "^0.8.5"` package and Laravel 5.8.
I also use summernote editor to save chapters and each one contains table and images.

Here is my code:

```
    public function pdfcreate(Request $res){
           $data=[];
           $data['notes'] =  Chapter::where('course_id',$res->course_id)->where('module_id',$res->module_id)-
                                     >leftjoin('courses','chapters.course_id','=','courses.id')
                                        ->get();
    $pdf = Course::where('id', $res->course_id)->first();
                                $data['pdfImg']= ($pdf->pdf_image)? $pdf->pdf_image:'';

                 if(count($data['notes'])>0){
                    $pdf = PDF::loadView('FrontPanel.pdf', $data);


                    return $pdf->download('module.pdf');
                  }else{
                    return redirect()->back()->with('status','Somthing is wrong.');
     }
```

And this is my view:

```
<html>
<head>

<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>
<meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <meta name="author" content="">

    <title>Pdf - Haats</title>


<style>
    @page { margin: 100px 25px; }

    .titel-text{width:80%;margin:auto;overflow: hidden !important;margin-top:80px;padding-bottom:100px}

    header { position: fixed; top: -50px; left: 50px; right: 50px; background-color: #ee455f; height: 5px;width:80%; }
    footer { position: fixed; bottom: -10px; left: 50px; right: 50px; background-color: #ee455f; height: 5px;width:80%; }

    </style>
</head>
<body>
<header>
<div class="border"></div> 

<div class="top-logo" style="width:100%;">
<?php if(isset($pdfImg)){?>
<img src="{{asset('public/Course_Image/'.$pdfImg)}}"   alt="back" style="height:400px;width:100%;margin-top:-12px">
<?php }else{?>
<img src="{{asset('public/Course_Image/1573897703i-know-nepal.png')}}" alt="back" style="height:400px;width:200px">
<?php }?>

</div>
</header>
<footer><div class="border"></div></footer>

<main>
<!-- <div class="logo-bottom" style="height:70px;background:red"></div> -->
<div class="titel-text" >

<?php 
    foreach($notes as $note){
    echo html_entity_decode($note->chap_content);
    }  
?>
</div>
</main>
</body>
</html>
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gMCZp.png)

Comment: try to use

`if(!empty($data))`

Comment: Can you post the full exception stactrace?

Comment: ErrorException (E_NOTICE)
Trying to access array offset on value of type null

Comment: I'm having the same issue using dompdf/dompdf 0.8.5 on CodeIgniter and PHP 7.4